# Selection sort array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, templates, selection-sort

I was trying to make my program sort the smallest number to the largest using selection sort. Everything compiles and runs, but the numbers are not in the right order when i try to use the program.

Can you look over my program to see if there is anything i can change to make it run correctly, because i tried everything and its still not showing the numbers in the right order.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void makearray(int data[],int n)
{
for ( int i =0 ; i < n ; i++)
    data[i]=(1+rand()%(1000-1+1));
}


template <class item, class sizetype>
int index_of_minimal(const item data[],sizetype i, sizetype n)
{
    int index=i;
    int first=data[i];

    for (i; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] < first)
            index = i;
    }

    return index;
}


template <class item, class sizetype>
void swap(item data[],sizetype i, sizetype j)
{
    int temp;

    temp=data[i];
    data[i]=data[j];
    data[j]=temp;
}


template <class item, class sizetype>
void selectionsort(item data[], sizetype n)
{
    int j;
    for(int i=0; i< n-1; i++)
    {
        j=index_of_minimal(data,i,n);
        swap(data,i,j);
    }

}

int main()
{
    int n;

    cout << "Enter n: " ;
    cin>>n;
    int data[n];
    makearray(data,n);

    cout << "unsorted array: " ;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << data[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    selectionsort(data, n);

    cout << "sorted array: " ;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << data[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `index_of_minimal` function, you need to reset the current smallest value(`first`) for the next comparison along with saving its index, otherwise another number, in your iteration, less that the original `first` value may still be larger than the ones you've already processed.

So it should be like this:

```
for (i; i < n; i++)
{
    if (data[i] < first)
    {
        index = i;
        first=data[i];//also save the new minimum value
    }
}
```